# My "Roman numerals to integer" code wrong

Tags: c++

Can someone tell me why my code is not working and giving the wrong output? I think the logic is correct so I'm not sure which errors I'm making. Thanks

```
    int romanToInt(string s) {
        unordered_map<char, int> map ={{'M',1000},{'D',500},{'C',100},{'L',50},{'X',10},{'V',5},{'I',1}};
        int result = 0;
        
        
        for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
        {
            if(map[s[i]]>=map[s[i+1]])
                result+=map[s[i]];
            else
                result+=(map[s[i+1]]-map[s[i]]);
        }
        
        return result;
    }
```

**Test case**

```
Input: "IV"
Output: 9
Expected: 4
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238818/discussion-on-question-by-b-m-my-roman-numerals-to-integer-code-wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that's wrong with your code is that you are comparing the ASCII values of characters rather than their numeric values. Also, you should not be adding `map[s[i+1]]` as you will be adding that value twice (once at step `i` and at step `i + 1`). Furthermore, you should be more careful with `s[i+1]`, as the index may be out of bounds. So first, check if the index is n - 1 (the last character).

Here is my approach:

```
int from_roman(string roman) {
    map<char,int> values={{'I',1},{'V',5},{'X',10},{'L',50},{'C',100},{'D',500},{'M',1000}};
    int i,n=roman.length(),val=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(i==n-1||values[roman[i]]>=values[roman[i+1]])
            val+=values[roman[i]];
        else
            val-=values[roman[i]];
    }
    return val;
}
```

Or a more compact version if you prefer it:

```
int from_roman(string roman) {
    map<char,int> values={{'I',1},{'V',5},{'X',10},{'L',50},{'C',100},{'D',500},{'M',1000}};  
    int i,n=roman.length(),val=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)val+=(i==n-1||values[roman[i]]>=values[roman[i+1]]?1:-1)*values[roman[i]];
    return val; 
}
```